# ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert Symbol into Integer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby

Doing one iteration with a hash in ruby, but some times in production(only on  production) getting this symbol error.

Controller

```
@d1 = Model.get_driver_details
```

Model

```
def get_driver_details
   driver_det = Hash.new
   driver_det[:driver_details] = Table.select('name as d_name, SUM(total) as 
   total_count').group('driver.id')
end
```

Result

```
{:driver_details=>[{:d_name=>"Tomy", :total_count=>"25"}]}
```

Iteration

```
total_count = 0
@d1[:driver_details].each do |driver|
   total_count += driver[:total_count].to_f 
end
```

So i am getting this error **ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert Symbol into Integer)** in this line **@d1[:driver_details].each do |driver|**

Comment: Is there any chance you put array instead of hash in `@d1` instance variable? How is this variable set in your code?

Comment: when i check the class, @d1 shows hash and this @d1[:driver_details] shows Array

Comment: It's proper behavior, but you already wrote (implicitly :)) that in production `@d1` sometimes turns out to be an array. So my next question is: How is `@d1` variable being set in your code?

Comment: @MarekLipka i have updated the code with my question

Comment: And what is "Query Result"?

Comment: @MarekLipka,  Query Result = Table.select('name as d_name, SUM(total) as total_count').
yes why i am telling in production because i can't see that in development environment

Answer (score 1):

This method is not returning the `driver_det` hash, it's only returning one entry in the hash and that entry is an array. (so it expects an integer for indexing, hence the error)

```
def get_driver_details
   driver_det = Hash.new
   driver_det[:driver_details] = Table.select('name as d_name, SUM(total) as 
   total_count').group('driver.id')
end
```

If you return the hash (reference it in the last line), you'll be ok.

```
def get_driver_details
   driver_det = Hash.new
   driver_det[:driver_details] = Table.select('name as d_name, SUM(total) as 
   total_count').group('driver.id')
   driver_det
end
```

I assume you plan to support other keys in future?